# I want to bring back COMMITED but then deleted files on my local repository after doing git reset hard

Tags: git, git-reset, git-reflog

I have staged and commited a very large folder (created and only present on my local repository) but then I did `git reset hard` to revert my big commit which was a mistake. However, luckily, I commited my folder before reseting it! I can track lost files (the hash ID) with `git reflog`. Now, **I am unsure what would be the correct action next.** I found online many advice but again many suggest hard reset... I would like to know if it is possible to bring back the deleted folder to my local repository. I want to merge it with my master. I did some other commits afterwards but I have them saved on both remote and local repository. My only concern now is that I am missing this one folder which is apparently deleted but luckily was commited so I hope there is a way to bring it back to my local repository and re-do the commiting but in smaller batches because the one single commit is to large to be pushed to gitlab.

I tried `git reflog <hash-ID>` after being suggested here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-in-git/ as a solution but I do not see any changes with
`git status` or `git checkout`.

However, after I typed into git bash `git checkout <hash-ID>` I got this message:

```html
$ git checkout 2f733ea
Updating files: 100% (1141/1141), done.
Note: switching to '2f733ea'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 2f733ea adding files needed for generating sampling points and maps
```

How do I save the lost/deleted files from the detached head back to my master?

Comment: `git reflog <hash-ID>` does not make sense. `git reflog HEAD` would make more sense. It allows you to find the hash of the commit that contains the files. I would then use `git checkout that_hash -- path/to/folder` to recover the files.

Comment: Just to clarify a concept: If you have a commit in your reflog that has that directory in then iit **is** in your local.

Comment: If you would like to get that directory into the current place that you are on, just run a checkout: `git checkout some-commit-id -- the-directory-i-want`.

Comment: Look closely what I wrote: `git checkout hash -- directory`. But you left out the `-- directory`. If you haven't switched around, yet, follow the hint: *undo this operation with: `git switch -`*; then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Well the message you got tells you what to do. Do `git switch -c <new-branch-name>`. This will create and checkout to a new branch that has the current commit at its tip.

If the hash-ID was the correct one, your new branch should now contain your 'big commit' and you can merge this into your master or whatever else you may want to do.